# Simulate tabs in an iPhone application

Tags: ios, cocoa, user-interface, tabs

I'm developing an iPhone application with latest SDK and XCode 4.2.

I'm using UINavigationController to manage the navigation of hierarchical content. On a children view, I need to simulate a tab view (I'm not sure it is called tab view) like this one:

[image]

**Note**: I have found this image at [Mobile UI Patterns](http://mobile-patterns.com/).

Instead of set tabs connect to upper bar, I need to connect this tab to its lower tab (in this image, Nearby will be connect to Mari Sheibley).

Do you know how can do simulate tabs?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a pre built controller for that, but you could of course build your own.

You would need to subclass UIView, figure out the size per tab, add the label, and change your navigation controller's view, depending on the clicked tab.